# Where can I find the misspelled Luke Skywlaker pen?

Tags: shopping, star-wars

There was a LEGO Star Wars snafu in which a buildable pen was released, and "Skywalker" was incorrectly spelled as "Sky**wla**ker". This was quickly remedied, and a corrected version was released.

I would like to find one of these "Skywlaker" pens. I have checked eBay, LEGO shop, Amazon and Bricklink and have not been able to find it. Does anyone have tips on where to look for these one-of-a-kind items?

Comment: Does anybody have a photo of one of these?  My googling came up with lots of low res images that weren't this thing.

Comment: Thats me and I still have it. :)

Comment: Hi Peter, can you share a photo of this strange pen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest I could find is a [forum thread](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?5055760-Can-anybody-help-me-with-a-Lego-Star-Wars-Collector-question) where a member called "slow 2.0" writes that (s)he has two of these and might be willing to sell one of them. The catch is the thread is from 2010 and the user hasn't been active in the forum since 2014.

**Update** Since the thread no longer has the image, here is how it looked like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Turns out we have two of these...[image]

Comment: Are you related to user "slow 2.0" mentioned in the other answer?